# save data to popupmenu

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, popupmenu, eventhandler

I have a popup-menu that has an option, add own material, and when this is chosen, a pushbutton is enabled that say SAVE. I alose have a bunch of edit-boxes.

What I want to do is to make a callback so whenever I click the SAVE, the data from one of the textboxes will possible to select in the popupmenu. when this is selected, I want to set the other edit-boxes to contain the same data that they did when I clicked the save button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure to fully understand what you want, but you can use the handle of the popup menu to get the string/string array in contains at the time you press the pushbutton. Then you can put those inside the textboxes using their handles as well.

For instance:

```
MyStrings = get(handlesToYourPopupMenu,'String');
```

or

```
MyStringsArray = cellstr(get(handlesToYourPopupMenu,'String'));
```

which contains the content of the popup menu as a cell array.

and

```
set(handlesToYourEditBox,'String',MyString);
```

Is that what you mean? If not please ask :)

EDIT:

To add the new data to the existing content of your text box, use concatenation. Since the content is in a cell array, you can do the following:

NewString = [OldString {CurrentString}];

where CurrentString is obtained with

```
get(hanlesToYourEditBox,'String');
```

Therefore to update the content of the popup menu you could write this:

```
set(handlesToPopUpMenu,'String',[MyStringsArray {get(hanlesToYourEditBox,'String')}]):
```

Comment: Let's say i have 3 values in the popupmenu from beofre (m1 m2 m3) and then the add layer. What I want to do is to get my string from the edit box say d1, and add it to the popupmenu (m1 m2 m3 d1).